# Animating multiple elements with unique a href tags

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm trying to create 4 or 5 different elements on a page that are animated to move randomly across the container element with each element having a unique link.

I'm struggling to understand how to generate 5 different div with unique links and have them all move randomly/independently of each other around the page.

JSFiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/vyvqLza7/

JS Code:

```
            $(document).ready(function () {
            newDiv();
            newDiv2();
        });

        function newDiv() {
            var $div = $("<div class='a'><a href='#'>");
            $(".animatedDivs").append($div);
            animateDiv();
            var $div2 = $("<div class='a'><a href='#'>");
            $(".animatedDivs").append($div2);
            animateDiv2();

            function animateDiv() {
                var newq = makeNewPosition();
                var oldq = $div.offset();
                var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

                $div.animate({top: newq[0],left: newq[1]}, speed, function () {animateDiv();});
            };

            function animateDiv2() {
                var newq = makeNewPosition();
                var oldq = $div.offset();
                var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

                $div.animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, function () { animateDiv(); });
            };
        }

        function makeNewPosition() {
            // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
            var h = 500-80;
            var w = $(window).width() - 80;
            var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
            var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);
            return [nh, nw];
        }

        function calcSpeed(prev, next) {
            var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
            var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);
            var greatest = x > y ? x : y;
            var speedModifier = .4;
            var speed = Math.ceil(greatest / speedModifier);
            return speed;

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer is correct as well for animating 5 divs.
To additionally create a random link, u can pass a `link` variable to your function `newDiv()`.
I don't know how your links should look like, but below is an example of how to create unique links as a random string.

```js
            $(document).ready(function () {
             var divCount = 5;
            
              for (i = 0; i < divCount; i++) { 
                newDiv(i+"_"+(new Date).getTime());
              }

            });

            function newDiv(link) {
                var $div = $("<div class='a'><a href='#"+link+"'>");
                $(".animatedDivs").append($div);
                animateDiv();


                function animateDiv() {
                    var newq = makeNewPosition();
                    var oldq = $div.offset();
                    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

                    $div.animate({top: newq[0],left: newq[1]}, speed, function () {animateDiv();});
                };

            }

            function makeNewPosition() {
                // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
                var h = 500-80;
                var w = $(window).width() - 80;
                var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
                var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);
                return [nh, nw];
            }

            function calcSpeed(prev, next) {
                var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
                var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);
                var greatest = x > y ? x : y;
                var speedModifier = .4;
                var speed = Math.ceil(greatest / speedModifier);
                return speed;

            }
```

```css
.lemonade {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

.a {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid lemonade">
 <div class="animatedDivs">
  &nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**:
The same example with manually set links:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/toffler01/g8c8ro7y/1/)

Comment: This is like, 99% of what I need, I just need to be able to manually set the links in either the JS or Google etc.

Comment: well, you can of course add a manually link to the function.

just make it an array `var links = ["https://www.google.at", "Link2", "Link3", "Link4", "Link5"];` and pass them to the for loop with `newDiv(links[i]);`

Like in this fiddle:
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/toffler01/g8c8ro7y/1/)

Comment: I removed my answer to support this one. It works fine and suits the needs of the question.

Answer (score 0):

First create your `divs` and after you create them you can target them to animate them. You don't need to create your `divs` with JS (but you can, if you need to)

HTML:

```
<div class='animatedDivs'>
  <div class='animate'>...</div>
  <div class='animate'>...</div>
  <div class='animate'>...</div>
  <div class='animate'>...</div>
  <div class='animate'>...</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.animate').forEach(animateDiv);

function animateDiv(div) {
  var newq = makeNewPosition();
  var oldq = div.offset();
  var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);
  div.animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, () => animateDiv(div));
}
```

This way, each div calls a new position for itself every time.

Comment: I've tried this but I'm clearly missing something as it's not working, I'm just not sure what. https://jsfiddle.net/8gcbqepd/